# Why the Sequence nextval is smaller than the max ID?

Tags: database, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a a spring boot application (version 1.5, java 8) and a PostgreSQL database, everything works well.

My primary key config is :

```
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "X_GENERATOR")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "X_GENERATOR",  sequenceName = "X_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "X_ID", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "NUMERIC(12)")
    private Long id;
```

I migrated my application to spring boot 2 and java 16. After the miration i have a problem with this error :

```
The increment size of the [X_SEQ] sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1]
```

So i have modified the SequenceGenerator by adding the allocationSize = 1 property :

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "X_GENERATOR",  sequenceName = "X_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
```

And now i have this error :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_X"
  Détail : Key (X_ID)=(21185) already exists.
```

So I looked for the max id, and the sequence next val and I didn't understand the results :

`SELECT MAX(X_ID) FROM X_table;` ===>  18917000

`SELECT nextval('X_SEQ');`===>  21286

Why all this mismatch and inconsistency between the max id and the nextval of the sequence ?

Comment: It seems your PostGresSQL `Sequence value` is wrong. I think this is not an issue with `Spring/Java` but its rather an issue with your DB. You should update your `X_SEQ` to the right value and test again.